# How to get last 5 rows using CTE?

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem using a CTE.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY #TEMPTABLE.Id order by #TEMPTABLE.Id) AS 'RowNo',
        #TEMPTABLE.Id,
        #TEMPTABLE.UserId,
        #TEMPTABLE.Code,
        #TEMPTABLE.CodeDesc
    FROM #TEMPTABLE
)
SELECT DISTINCT Id, UserId,Code,CodeDesc          
FROM CTE
where RowNo <=5
```

From this query, I want to get the last 5 rows. But I am always getting first 5 rows. Please give me a solution in this.

Comment: Try using `DESC` in your `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Do you really want the RowNo and the CTE? If not, there is a quite simpler way to achieve that.

Comment: I want to get last 5 datas from a group data.Please let me the other way

Comment: Does your `#Template.id` hold duplicate values?

Comment: Yes #TEMPTABLE.Id will be having duplicate values

Comment: Ah, then the solution would be good enough. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add descending (`DESC`) order to `ROW_NUMBER's` `ORDER BY` clause, by default it is ascending (`ASC`) that's why you getting first 5 rows, try in following:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY #TEMPTABLE.Id ORDER BY #TEMPTABLE.ActionId DESC) AS 'RowNo',
        #TEMPTABLE.Id,
        #TEMPTABLE.UserId,
        #TEMPTABLE.Code,
        #TEMPTABLE.CodeDesc
    FROM #TEMPTABLE
)
SELECT DISTINCT RowNo,Id, UserId,Code,CodeDesc          
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNo <=5
```

Comment: Hi I have added Desc in the order by. For your information the Id is unique id.Please check the below table.                                                                         RowNo Id UserId Code Desc
1 45 83 A001 Blocked
2 45 84 A002 Body Fluids
3 45 88 A006 Cracked
4 45 91 A009 Damaged
5 45 93 A011 Dirty